# Merging [tag:clothing] and [tag:clothes]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

[clothing](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clothing) and [clothes](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clothes) seem synonymous. Let's merge them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been actioned [clothing](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clothing) has been nominated as the destination as it had more questions